# Sort dictionary based on count

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have the following code that works great. It get my IP address out of a file and counts how many times they appear in the logfile.

```
def count_ips():
    fp=open('logfile','r')
    store=[]
    while 1:
            line=fp.readline()
            if not line:
                    break
            if line[-1:] == '\n':
                    line=line[:-1]
            data1=line.split('"')
            data2=data1[0].split(' ')
            store.append({'IP':data2[0],'Date':data2[3]+' '+data2[4],'Action':' '.join(data1[1:-2]),'Browser':' '.join(data1[-2:])})
    fp.close()
    count={}
    for i in store:
            if i['IP'] in count:
                    count[i['IP']] +=1
            else:
                    count[i['IP']] =1

    avg=0
    cnt=0
    for i in count:
            avg+=count[i]
            cnt+=1
    avg=avg/cnt
    print 'average hit is: %i' % avg

    for i in count:
           if count[i] > 10:
                   print i +' %i' % count[i]
count_ips()
```

I dont really know how I got to this point but in this section. I would like to sort by the count before I print it out. Biggest number on the bottom.

```
    for i in count:
           if count[i] > 10:
                   print i +' %i' % count[i]
```

I feel at this point im just looking at things wrong and dont see the easy fix for my little dilemma.

Thank you for you help!
Jason

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that `count` is your dict of IP->Count, then:

```
from operator import itemgetter
sorted_counts = sorted(count.iteritems(), key=itemgetter(1))
for ip, cnt in sorted_counts:
    print ip, 'had', cnt, 'results'
```

Comment: Sometimes I feel like I will never get this. Thank you very much for the assistance!

Answer (score 1):

so assume that you have a dictionary d which contain keys that are IPs and values are the counts.

```
>>> d = {'1.1.1.1':5, '2.2.2.2':4}
```

Here is what I would do in a one liner:

```
>>> sorted((d[ip], ip) for ip in d)
[(4, '2.2.2.2'), (5, '1.1.1.1')]
```

You can also use parameter reverse=True to sorted the list in reversed order.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I have to treat dictionaries as data I use pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame(list(dict.items()), columns= ['IP','count']).sort_values('count')
```

Notice that the items from the dictionary are called with `dict.items()` and then passed to a list. If using python 2.X then you should omit the `list()` call.